# How to Authenticate to Magnolia Rest endpoint from WCS

Tags: rest, authentication, tags, magnolia, wcs

I created rest endpoint in Magnolia so when I want to test it from external api (WCS) I got formuler to authenticate in response.

So how can I give credentials to my endpoint using wcs rest [Rest Tag](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_8.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.component-services.doc/refs/rwvwcfresttag.htm) with secure way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As described in documentation you need to provide username and password with your request or configure /.rest uri to not require authentication. See more in [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/REST+API?desktop=true&macroName=multiexcerpt#RESTAPI-Authenticating).

Optionally if you want to get login challenge rather than login form for unauthenticated requests, you need to configure basic login handler for that. More info also in documentation.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Thanks Jan for your help.

Comment: for Rest Tag I pass credentials using header Tag as below

I simulate the curl command : curl  --user login:password http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.rest/nodes/v1/website/demo-project

<wcf:rest var="contriesResult" format="raw" url="..........">
    <wcf:header name="Authorization" 
       value="Basic c3VwZXJ1c2VyOnN1cGVydXNlcg=="/>
</wcf:rest>

the value "c3VwZXJ1c2VyOnN1cGVydXNlcg==" is login:password encoded in Base64